# Creating a login portal for my WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables

Me and my room mate often have a lot of friends come over to our apartment to play games and what not. So we are talking a lot of devices connecting to my router (cell phones, tablets, laptops etc .. some times even PS3). I currently have a DD-wrt based router.

What I want is the following - Create some kind of a login portal, the way they have in airports and stuff. The first time their device signs in they are shown a page where they enter their name. Then they hit "submit" at which point their internet starts "working".

I attached a USB wifi dongle to my wired Linux box. Installed dnsmasq dhcpserver, installed iptables and got it to work as a "router" by sharing out eth0 over wlan0 (enabling ip_forward, masquerading all that good stuff).. That part works.

How do I do the login portal thing? I am not interested in passwords (all though as a next step that would be cool). My place is like a central "hub" for a lot of my gaming pals, so often I have folks who are friends of friends and I just want to keep a basic track of what's going on etc.

Comment: Look up "linux captive portal". You'll need Apache + MySQL (for the webpage) and (probably) squid (a proxy to manage the redirect of clients to your login page)...

Answer (score 0):

Install pfsense on the box you want to use as the router - It has the software you require built in. Plenty of tutorials about to show you how on http://pfsense.org/

The 2.2beta has better USB wifi support - Most atheros/ralink chipsets supported, but no wireless N. Just B/G.